# React Formik : how to use custom function onChange and onConfirmChange for request input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I would like to have my 2nd PinInput send an error message when the password is not the same :

```
class PasswordInput extends Component {
    state = "";

    onChange = () => {
        this.setState({
            value: this.state.value
        })
    }

    onConfirmChange = () => {
        this.setState({
            value: !this.state.value});
    }


    render() {
        const { field, form } = this.props;

        console.log(form.errors[field.name]);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <label className="title-password">Saisi ton code à 4 chiffres</label>
                <PinInput {...field} className="pincode-input-container"
                    length={4}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="numeric"
                    secret='true'
                    inputStyle={{
                        background: 'white',
                        height: '72px',
                        borderRadius: '20px',
                        borderColor: form.errors[field.name] ? 'red' : 'transparent'
                    }}
                />
                {form.errors[field.name] &&
                    <div>
                        {form.errors[field.name]}
                    </div>}

                <label className="title-password">Confirme le code</label>
                <PinInput {...field} length={4}
                    onChange={this.onConfirmChange}
                    type="numeric"
                    secret="true"
                    inputStyle={{
                        background: 'white',
                        border: 'none',
                        height: '72px',
                        borderRadius: '20px',
                        borderColor: form.errors[field.name] ? 'red' : 'transparent'
                    }}
                />
                {form.errors[field.name] &&
                    <div>
                        {form.errors[field.name]}
                    </div>}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default PasswordInput;
```

I create 2 functions that call the type onChange (and onConfirmChange) 2 input, but I do not know how to do it.

I have an idea beginning but I can not implement it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: if you are using Yup validation you can have that check coded into your validation schema

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

If we use your logic to validate the passwords it should be:

```
yourOnChange = (e) => {
    // Whatever logic goes here ...
    // ...

    // Forkmik's onChange
    this.props.onChange(e);
  };
```

Option 2:

You can do [field level validation:](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#field-level-validation)

Example:

```
 // Assuming this.props is formiks's props.  
 // some elements here...
 <Field name="password1" />

 <Field name="password2"
   onChange={this.props.onChange}
   onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
   validate={validatePassword2} />

// somewhere in your component...
 validatePassword2 = (value) => {
  let error;
  if (value === this.props.values[password1]) {
    error = 'Passwords don\'t match!';
  }
  return error;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response, but for the option 2 its dosn't work because my **PasswordInput** is called in a different component like this :

> RegisterPage (content Yup, Field, ErrorMessage from formik)

```javascript
<Field name="password" component={InputForm} />
```

Comment: It should still work for Option 2, you need to pass the props of Field. Option 2 should be the best approach. Check the [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it in nice way, I recommend using yup for validation and do conditional validation in the schema itself.

But to achieve this, you can also do the comparison manually, same way you are accessing the errors state of formik - just grab values instead for each field, and conditionally render your error message based on the comparison result.